# How can I in R use the mutate function to add a column with values from another indexed list?

Tags: r, dplyr, mutate

I have a dataframe (df) in R :

> df

| Some_value_I_care_about | Gene_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | 1 |
| 4567 | 2 |
| 6789 | 2 |

Additionally I have a list (which I am assuming is indexed):

> s4_file$genes

[1] Gene A [2] Gene B

I want to add a column in df which uses this indexed list to draw out the "Gene" names and adds it:

> df_final

| Some_value_I_care_about | Gene_ID | Gene_Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 1 | Gene A |
| 4567 | 2 | Gene B |
| 6789 | 2 | Gene B |

I used this but and wasnt sure if it was doing as expected:

df_final <- df %>% mutate(Gene_Name = s4_file$gene[Gene_ID])

Comment: Depends on the structure of `s4_gile$genes`. If it is in the correct order, this will work. If not, then it won't. You say *"which I am assuming is indexed"* - would suggest checking that assumption.

Comment: Perhaps `df |> dplyr::mutate(Genes = factor(Gene_ID, labels = s4_file$genes)) `?

Comment: I think that would work, but you probably want `s4_file$gene` to be a character vector instead of a list.  (Assuming it contains only character data).  A more common way to do this is with a `left_join` on `Gene_ID` with a second data frame.  It's kind of error-prone and inconvenient to have to manage the indexing like this.

Comment: `df %>% left_join(data.frame(Some_value_I_care_about = s4_file$genes) |> mutate(Gene_ID = row_number())`

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition of doing `s4_file$gene[Gene_ID]` is quite right and robust. It means you know that the data in your two datasets are not aligned.

You can do the `apply()` operation on every row of df and find the corresponding 'genes' in 's4_file$genes' using associated 'Gene_ID'.

```
df%<>%apply(1, function(x) {c(x, Gene_Name=s4_file$genes[x['Gene_ID']])}) %>%t() %>%as.data.frame()
df
  Some_value_I_care_about Gene_ID Gene_Name
1                   12345       1    Gene A
2                    4567       2    Gene B
3                    6789       3    Gene C
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be cleaner and more reliable as a join, where we put the gene names into a table which maps the row (which we will rename as `Gene_ID`) of the lookup table to the same column in our original table. Then the join will use that shared column to link the data from the two tables.

```
library(dplyr)
df |>
  left_join(data.frame(Some_value_I_care_about = s4_file$genes) |> 
            mutate(Gene_ID = row_number())
```